# Check for underscore wrapped any valid Windows filename characters except underscore and csv extension

Tags: java, regex, windows, filenames, file-extension

I'm still very new to regex, so I think I can determine whether a string ends with a case-insensitive `.csv`:

```
(\\.(?i)(csv))
```

However, I do not know how to check that everything before that is at least one valid Windows filename character except an underscore, one underscore, and at least one valid Windows filename character except an underscore.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regex for starters: `[\\dA-Za-z]+_[\\dA-Za-z]+(\\.(?i)(csv))`.

It takes the part you had checking for the `.csv` and adds a little more in front of it.  It can be broken down into smaller parts:

1. `[\\dA-Za-z]+`: any digit (`\d`), a-z case insensitive. At least one (`+`), could be more.
2. `_`: exactly one underscore
3. `[\\dA-Za-z]+`: any digit, a-z case insensitive. At least one (`+`), could be more.
4. `(\\.(?i)(csv))`: your already existing `.csv` check.

Comment: I thank you very much for that extra work!  In my case, I can force users to only use alphanumeric.  Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Just for the record, [there seem to be some reserved chars for filenames that you CANNOT use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions).  I think it's a safe bet just using the simple alphanumeric.  ALSO:  The exrtra parenthesis in your regex, if you don't need to capture things specifically in groups, I suggest removing them as they can slow down a regex.  I think the only ones you need are around the `(?i)`.

Comment: Lol, sorry about that.  It didn't come out right.  It's the backslash.  Thanks for getting back to me so quickly!

Comment: Oh snap, sorry.  This is a `java` tagged post and I didn't realize.  I normally do all my regex testing for SO on Rubular.com which is a light Ruby one (real simple and clean).  When I paste the regex in I don't escape the chars properly.  In regex use backslash to escape special chars like the `\d` for digits.  In Java, you have to escape the escape so that Java reads it as `\d` instead of seeing a Java backslash and looking for a Java special string char after.  For all the backslashes, use an extra one (`\\d` for example)... should do the trick.  I'll edit the answer to reflect this.